# Как создать apex отчет в JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день создал такой мини тест хотел получить отчеты на Apex но незнаю как установить данный плагин. Буду рад если объясните как установить данный плагин

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о [Apdex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apdex) - то проще всего [сгенерировать HTML отчет](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), для этого запустите свой тест в режиме non-GUI

```
jmeter -n -t /путь/к/тесту.jmx -l /путь/к/результатам.jtl -e -o /путь/к/папке/с/HTML/отчетом
```

Получится что-то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же все-таки это [Oracle Apex](https://apex.oracle.com/en/), например [Apex Reporting](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=myapex:apex-reporting), то вы можете ему скормить [.jtl файл](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) с результатами теста, это простой CSV который можно положить в любую базу

Плагины для JMeter устанавливаются следующим образом:

- .jar файл(ы) с плагином копируются в папку lib/ext
- зависимости (если нужны) копируются в папку lib
- для активации нужен будет перезапуск JMeter

Посмотрите в раздел [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) документации